# How to use Interaction Trigger on button with MouseUp and MouseDown events in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a button that needs to execute two separate commands (one to start something and one to stop it). After doing some research the System.Windows.Interactivity.dll seemed to provide an easy way to accomplish this. But it doesn't work with the left mouse button (it does work if I use an event like *MouseDoubleClick* or *MouseRightButtonDown*, but not *MouseDown*, *MouseUp*, or *MouseRightButtonDown*)...it seems as if the button consumes the event itself and the interaction.trigger never sees it. I provided a snippet of my XAML below, what can I do to get around this behavior?

```
<Button Content="DoStuff">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding StartCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseUp">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding StopCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Comment: have you even taken a look in button class to check what events are available for use ?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button.aspx

Comment: Yes, that was the first thing I did. I have tried PreviewDown/Up, MouseDown/Up, PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown/Up, MouseLeftButtonDown/Up, and PreviewMouseDown/Up and none of them work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `PreviewMouseDown` and `PreviewMouseUp` instead

Comment: This works, thanks. I tried it earlier but had a typo in my command. Do you know what the difference is with the "Preview" events vs their counter parts?

Comment: @Omribitan any ideas why the tunneling Preview worked but the bubble didn't ? , i'm guessing some element in the why got in the middle ..

Comment: @AXG1010 WPF introduced a new concept called [Routed Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx). The idea is that the events are either first handled by their creator and climb up the control hirarchy (Bubbled events) or handled by the root element first and tunnel down to thier creator (Tunneled events) - those are the `Preview` events. You can learn more about it [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/464926/To-bubble-or-tunnel-basic-WPF-events)

Answer (score 0):

mouseleftbuttondown , mouseleftbuttonup